# Showing inverse of multivariate holomorphic map is holomorphic using real analysis techniques

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem, inverse-function-theorem

I'm grading for a graduate *real* analysis course and looking through the text, trying to do some problems before the term starts so I can stay ahead of things. I found the following exercise in the section on the Inverse and Implicit Function Theorems.

> Identify $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ with $\mathbb{C}^n$ by $(x , y) \mapsto x + iy$. Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ be open, and let $F : U \to \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ be $C^1$. Assume $p \in U, DF(p)$ invertible. If $F^{-1}: V \to U$ is the inverse to $F$, show that if $F$ is holomorphic, then so is $F^{-1}$.

The definition of holomorphic for a map $F : \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is given in an earlier exercise as satisfying the Riemann-Cauchy equations, or equivalently as
$$DF(x) \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} DF(x),$$
where the exercise is to show that these are equivalent, then generalize to higher dimensions.

I'm at an impasse here with how to show this fact using *real* analysis. It seems fairly clear to me that if I could understand these as maps from $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ to $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, I could just say that the inverse of an invertible complex matrix is an invertible complex matrix and call it, but I don't know how to do this one with these techniques.

I figured that what I'd want to do is show that if $DF(x)$ satisfied the Cauchy-Riemann equations, then so did $DF(x)^{-1}$. I tried using some linear algebra trickery, describing the "Cauchy-Riemann matrices" as real $2n \times 2n$ matrices with blocks of the form $\begin{smallmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{smallmatrix}$, and constructing an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra isomorphism between these and the $n \times n$ complex matrices so I could manipulate the complex matrices, but showing the isomorphism was multiplicative got out of hand and I felt fairly sure the author had an easier, more analytic approach in mind when he wrote it.

So please help me! I'm at a loss on how to show the inverse of a non-singular holomorphic map is holomorphic, and would love your advice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have $$DF(x)A= A DF(x) \quad (1)$$ where $A$ encodes the CR differential equations. You know that $B=DF(x)^{-1}$ exists. Multiply $(1)$ by $B$ from both sides and you get $A DF(x)^{-1} = DF(x)^{-1} A$. I do not understand your comment about complex matrices.

Comment: How do you mean $A$ “encodes the CR differential equations”?

Comment: You need more assumptions, see how it fails with $z \to e^z, \Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{C}^*$, you'll have only the analyticity of the local inverses. Moreover that a complex function is holomorphic just means $f(a+v) = f(a)+Mv+o(\|v\|)$ for some complex-linear map $M=M_a$ (if $f$ is $C^1$ but not complex differentiable then $M$ is only real linear), that $M$ is invertible means $f^{-1}(f(a)+w)) = a+M^{-1}w+o(\|w\|)$ so $f^{-1}$ is complex differentiable at $f(a)$.

Comment: @reuns I’m pretty sure it only means to talk about local inverses, giving that it’s actually asking about DF^{-1}(p).

Comment: Think of $F: \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^n : (x_1, x_2) \mapsto (F_1(x_1,x_2), F_2(x_1,x_2))$.
And $$DF = \begin{bmatrix}D_{x_1}F_1 & D_{x_1}F_2\\D_{x_2}F_1 & D_{x_2}F_2\end{bmatrix}$$

The Cauchy-Riemann conditions are
$$D_{x_1}F_1 = D_{x_2}F_2$$ and $$D_{x_2}F_1 = -D_{x_1}F_2$$

Comment: @PaulSinclair So I wanna commute with $$\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{0}_{n \times n} & - I_{n \times n} \\ I_{n \times n} \mathbf{0}_{n \times n} $$ is that right?

Comment: Yes, the block matrix version of $i$.